# remote assessment of an SMD slide switch

Tags: switches, surface-mount

I am designing a PCB with one of [these](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/MINI-micro-Slide-Switch-On-OFF-2-Position-1P2T-SPDT-Miniature-Horizontal-Slide-Switch-SMD-7/32841341185.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.1.267f76f87eebO4&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10130_10324_10342_10547_10325_10343_10340_10341_10548_10192_10190_10084_10083_10618_10630_10307_10301_10303_5711211_5722315_10313_10059_10184_10534_100031_10103_10627_10626_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620_5711311_10142,searchweb201603_36,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=af559e8b-3478-4b6b-90a5-1c2627e6f942-0&algo_pvid=af559e8b-3478-4b6b-90a5-1c2627e6f942&transAbTest=ae803_3&priceBeautifyAB=0) switches. However i have not received them yet and so i cant test which pins are connected to which when the switch is on and off.there is a little mechanical drawing on the website but i dont think it helps. im guessing that the 4 pins on the short edges are purely for fixing to the PCB and the other 3 are the conductors. maybe with the solitary one being connected to either of the other ones depending on what position the switch is in....  does anyone have any experience with these switched that could enlighten me? many thanks.

Comment: My experience is, whichever way you pick..it will be the other way.

Answer (score 3):

If you look close at the drawing you will see this.

[image]

That definitely implies the centre pin is the common.

Sliding the lever to whichever end with short that pin to the appropriate end pin.

But you never know.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had that exact SPDT switch, but the ones I've had short the middle pin with the side pin that is on the same side as the moving part of the switch. This is also probably the easiest thing to do mechanically.